# Add foreign key constraint for denormalized columns in detail tables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, foreign-key, sql-server-2017, cardinality-estimates

When a detail table contains denormalized data, should denormalized columns be included in foreign key relationships between the master table and detail table?  Here's more details:

We have a master/detail pair of fact tables: an `Invoice` table with about 1M rows and an `InvoiceDetail` table with about 20M rows. To improve reporting performance for date-range queries we've partially denormalized by adding `SaleDate` to the `InvoiceDetail` and creating a covering index on `SaleDate` with the other columns INCLUDEd.

There's already a foreign key relationship between the `InvoiceId` column in both tables.

But SQL Server is unaware that the `SaleDate` in both tables is the same if the `InvoiceId` is the same. Should I help SQL Server to know about the relationship?  If so, how?

Finally, will adding denormalized columns to foreign keys improve cardinality estimates when joining the master/detail pages by telling SQL Server that cardinality shouldn't be reduced when filtering both tables by the same a date range?  If not, then what's the benefit of maintaining this foreign key relationship that includes the denormalized column?

We're running SQL Server 2014 an are soon upgrading to SQL 2017, if that matters to the answer.

Comment: You mention fact table, is this a dedicated reporting data warehouse? Or are you trying to improve reporting performance over an OLTP database?

Comment: @MarkStorey-Smith - It's an OLTP database, but these two tables are optimized for read-only reporting and are updated by an out-of-band process rather than being involved in each transaction.  So from the perspective of reporting on these two tables, it's more like a data warehouse use-case than OLTP.

Comment: Can you share schema and an example problem query, execution plan, server specs? What's the response time for typical queries currently and what are the hopes/expectations for "good"?

Comment: Maybe you want to hear it from someone else, but as I said last time foreign keys unfortunately do not improve cardinality estimates. How large is the Invoice table in KB?

Comment: Sorry @JoeObbish, was posting this on behalf of a co-worker who was not familiar with your godlike skills when it comes to the dark arts of cardinality estimation troubleshooting.  ;-) As you might guess from the wording of this question, I was dubious that foreign-key extension was going to be useful for cardinality, but was wondering if might be useful for other reasons. The Invoice table is ~85MB. InvoiceDetail table is ~1.3GB.  Also, I couldn't find that Connect item you mentioned in your other answer. Was it lost in UserVoice migration? https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/

Comment: Hah, I wish. If you have a lot of issues with estimation have you considered just denormalizing the table? With only 85 MB you're looking at about 1.5 GB in extra space. Might be okay depending on your process for updating it. With SQL Server 2017 columnstore is a lot better so you could consider that as well if you combine the tables. Connect item seems to be gone. https://web.archive.org/web/20160703025231/https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/772232/make-optimizer-estimations-more-accurate-by-using-metadata

Comment: Yep, @JoeObbish, we're definitely considering full denormalization, although probably a move to columnstore seems like the better long-term solution once our hoster gets their act together and starts supporting SQL 2017.